# Private Route is not rendering About Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

so I have the private routes set up in App.js. The other components in the private routes render correctly. The About Component isnt rendering. Before I was getting an error saying something along the lines of expected a string but got an object. Now I can goto the about page and the error is gone. I console.log props and slides but it doesnt show up in the console. I am passing props(slides) in the Private route to About.js.

```
Hi. Ive been stuck on this for two days now. PRivate route doesnt show the About component. It works on all other components. Code is below.Any help is greatly appreciated.
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Nav/>
      <main>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/home" component={Home} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/resources" component={Resources} />
          <PrivateRoute path = "/about" component={ About} slides= {SliderData} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/mealplan" component={MealPlan}   />
        </Switch>

        <Route exact path="/" component={SignUp} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

function About(slides) {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const length = slides.length


  if (!Array.isArray(slides) || slides.length <= 0) {
    return null;
  }

  const nextSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1);
  };

  const prevSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current === 0 ? length - 1 : current - 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <section className="slider">
        <FaArrowAltCircleLeft onClick={prevSlide} className="left-arrow" />
        <FaArrowAltCircleRight onClick={nextSlide} className="right-arrow" />
        {SliderData.map((slide, index) => {
          return (
            <div className={index === current ? "slide-active" : "active"} key={index}
            >
              {index === current && (
                <img src={slide.image} alt="dog" className="dog-img" />
              )}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </section>
    </>

Private Route 
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) =>  {
    return(<Route {...rest} render={
        (props) => {
            if (localStorage.getItem("token")) {
                return <Component {...props}/>;
            } else {
                return(<Redirect to='/login'/>);
            }
        }
    }/>);
};


Like I said it works on the other components but not the About Component. I have tried everything I can think of but cant get it to render
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to pass additional props through `PrivateRoute` to the component but don't pass them all the way through. You only pass the route props through.

PrivateRoute

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) =>  {
  return(
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={
        (props) => {
          if (localStorage.getItem("token")) {
            return <Component {...props}/>; // <-- only route props from `render`
          } else {
            return(<Redirect to='/login'/>);
          }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Refactor the `PrivateRoute` so it renders more like a plain `Route` component.

```
const PrivateRoute = (props) =>  {
  return localStorage.getItem("token") ? (
    <Route {...props} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect to='/login'/>
  );
};
```

Now use the `render` prop to render the `About` component and pass the additional prop(s) through.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Nav/>
      <main>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/home" component={Home} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/resources" component={Resources} />
          <PrivateRoute
            path="/about"
            render={props => (
              <About {...props} slides= {SliderData} />
            )}
          />
          <PrivateRoute path="/mealplan" component={MealPlan} />
        </Switch>

        <Route exact path="/" component={SignUp} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Ensure you are accessing the `slides` prop correctly. I.E. `props.slides`.

```
function About({ slides }) {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);
  const length = slides.length

  if (!Array.isArray(slides) || slides.length <= 0) {
    return null;
  }

  const nextSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current === length - 1 ? 0 : current + 1);
  };

  const prevSlide = () => {
    setCurrent(current === 0 ? length - 1 : current - 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <section className="slider">
        <FaArrowAltCircleLeft onClick={prevSlide} className="left-arrow" />
        <FaArrowAltCircleRight onClick={nextSlide} className="right-arrow" />
        {SliderData.map((slide, index) => {
          return (
            <div className={index === current ? "slide-active" : "active"} key={index}
            >
              {index === current && (
                <img src={slide.image} alt="dog" className="dog-img" />
              )}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </section>
    </>
  );
}
```